# Get jquery variable into php variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im having the following code as a part of a jQuery script presenting the result in a div

```
var html = "";
//Displaying profile
if (options.display_profile) {
    html += "<div class='instagram_profile'" + styles.profile_container + ">";
    html += "<img class='instagram_profile_image' src='" + data.profile_pic_url  + "' alt='"+ (is_tag ? data.name + " tag pic" : data.username + " profile pic") + "'" + styles.profile_image + (options.lazy_load ? " loading='lazy'" : '') + " />";
    if (is_tag)
        html += "<p class='instagram_tag'" + styles.profile_name + "><a href='https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + options.tag + "' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>#" + options.tag + "</a></p>";
    else
        html += "<p class='instagram_username'" + styles.profile_name + ">@" + data.full_name + " (<a href='https://www.instagram.com/" + options.username + "' rel='noopener' target='_blank'>@" + options.username + "</a>)</p>";

    if (!is_tag && options.display_biography)
        html += "<p class='instagram_biography'" + styles.profile_biography + ">" + data.biography + "</p>";

    html += "</div>";
}
```

Now i want to pass by the result into a php variable so that i can pass it into a mysql table insted of printing it out in

```
<div id='instagram-feed3' class='instagram_feed'></div>
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You need to either submit a form or use AJAX.

Comment: Typing your question title into Google verbatim, would have gotten you lots of results already. _Please_ do a bit of basic research, before you ask here.

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar suggested in the comment, you need to do an AJAX call (supported by jQuery $.post() & $.ajax()).
When the data is submitted, you can get the variables in PHP with $_POST["name_of_var"] (Thats the PHP variable, that stores the POST values).

[Here](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@sogata/how-to-insert-data-to-mysql-from-php-using-jquery-ajax) is a great tutorial on how to do that and with everything you need to know.

BUT: Think about it, you like to store HTML in a database. So why is that not a good idea?

A big rule for databases: everything you can calculate from the stored data should not be saved. When you do this, you keep your data dynamic - When you do this, you have to change just one variable to affect the results of other calculations.
Storing the whole calculated HTML would make it very hard to edit it afterwards.
The user changes his .profile_pic_url? Update a cell in a database table and let JS calculate the new frontend (Yes, every time, when the user views that content).
Keep the HTML in your frontend, and in the future, you will thank yourself for doing that. In some cases you create some HTML on the server site and in some cases that's completely fine, as long as it is dynamic and easy to modify.

Conclusion: Keep your code as dynamic as possible to make things easier in the future.
Think about creating a table with the user data and calculating the frontend from that data.